# How to delete value from the database which is entered into my textView after pressing delete button?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I want to delete the TextView string value from the firebase database which after deleting will return the value as true. How can we then integrate more qr code values under the same key qrCode as shown in the image below.

Image for database :

[image]

Basically a qr code scanner will be inbuilt in this app which will give us the string value in TextView field which we want to verify with our database on firebase.

```java
package com.vidmun.dhananjay.qrscanner;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        TextView qrCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);


        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mainTest();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    public void mainTest() {
        final TextView qrCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
        final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("qrCode");
         rootRef.child("qrCode").orderByChild("data").equalTo(String.valueOf(qrCode)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("qrCode/data")) {
                    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Not Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

The expected output is the execution of the if condition but else condition is being executed.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("qrCode");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myRef.addChildEventListener(new MyChildEventListener());


    }

   public void deleteValueFromDb(View view){

    myRef.child("data").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Not Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

         @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
             throw databaseError.toException();
         }
     });
   }

private class MyChildEventListener implements ChildEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "childAdded " + dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "childChanged " + dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i(TAG, "childRemoved " + dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "childMoved " + dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i(TAG, "childMoved " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is with the condition you are checking in onDatachange(). Because of the path "qrCode/data" will always return false.

You can change the "data" with your intended value from editText filed.

And also you can use custom callback listener to get notified of the value when removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

You need to handle this list by looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in your `onDataChange`:

```
final TextView qrCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("qrCode");
rootRef.orderByChild("data").equalTo(String.valueOf(qrCode)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                snapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Deleting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

The changes compared to your code:

- Removed the `child("qrCode")` in your query, since you already have that node in `rootRef`.
- We now loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get each individual search result (even if there is only one).